# How to fix image scaling when set from Swift code

Tags: swift3, uiimageview, ios10

I'm trying to set images from my Swift code and display them in table view cells but when I set them from Swift code they are scaled or in totally different place.

Did anybody have similar issue?

My code:

```
var datasources = ["mapmyrun","fitbitlogo"]



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "datasourcecell", for: indexPath) as? DataSourceCell else{
        fatalError("cell is not an instance of DataSourceCell")
    }
    cell.imageView?.contentMode =  UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    let image = UIImage(named: datasources[indexPath.row])

    cell.imageView?.image = image

    return cell


}
```

Result from code:

[image: code]
Result when I set it manually. It is perfect fit:

[image: manually]

Comment: are you trying to populate the image that covers the `entire cell` ? and do you hooked any `IB outlet` for `imageView` in your `datasourcecell` class.

Comment: I guess it seems you have not added any autolayout constraints to your imageView. Add Leading, Trailing, Top and Bottom Constraints and set the image content mode to aspect fit. It should work.